# Another definition of local coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

True or false:  Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1(X)]$-module.  The homology of $X$ with local coefficients in $A$ is equal to the $H_*(\tilde{X} \times_{\pi_1(X)} A,\mathbb{Z})$.

Why i'm interested:  This would simplify the definition of homology with local coefficients considerably.  Homology with local coefficients would then just be homology of a space called a 'local coefficient system'.

Comment: what is the object $\tilde{X} \times_{\pi_1(X)} A$ --- a module, a topological space, or maybe something else?

Comment: This is a push out of the universal cover of X and A by the action of $\pi_1(X)$

Comment: The space $\tilde{X} \times_{\pi_1(X)} A$ is $\tilde{X} \times A/((xg,a) \sim (x,ga))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I think, I do not understand your question in its entirety, because I don't know how to take a pushout of objects of two *different* categories)

If you want to compute $H_*(X,A)$, you actually should take the complex $C_*(X,A):=C_*(\tilde{X},\mathbb Z) \times_{\pi_1(X)} A$.

In general, for an arbitrary $\pi_1(X)$-module the homology groups $H_*(X,A)$ do not equal the homology of some topological space, because $H_0(X,A)$ does not necessary equal $\mathbb Z$ even if $X$ is path-connected.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  The space $\tilde{X} \times_{\pi_1(X)} A$ is $\tilde{X} \times A/((xg,a) \sim (x,ga))$

Comment: @user062295 then you obtain a wrong answer for a trivial $A$

Comment: Right.  For $A$ with a trivial $\pi_1(X) \curvearrowright A$, the space is $\tilde{X}/\pi_1(X) \times A$.  Then $H_n(\tilde{X} \times_{\pi_1(X)} A,\mathbb{Z})=H_n(X,H_0(A))=H_n(X,\mathbb{Z}[A])$.  This is assuming that the higher homology groups of $A$ are 0(as a topological space).